# Is the attraction between two magnets stronger than a magnet and metal?

Tags: electromagnetism

I can imagine that it's stronger but what are the mechanisms in place that make this happen? And how much stronger?

Comment: Welcome. It would be nice, if you could describe your state of knowledge. What are your ideas? Do you know why a magnet attracts steel? Or, what is your "picture" of a magnetic dipole?

Comment: I know nothing about electromagnetic forces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinkable are three scenarios.

1. You use two identical permanent magnets. The attraction between them is stronger than that between a magnet and a magnetisable metal.
   The reason for this is that the additional magnetic field of the magnetized metal comes from the alignment of the electrons or protons with their magnetic dipole moment to the applied magnetic field. These electrons have their own orientation equilibrium and the magnet cannot align the same amount of electrons in the metal as the magnet.
2. You use two permanent magnets of different strength. The attraction of the stronger magnet and the metal *could* be greater than between the two magnets.
   The explanation is basically the same as in case 1. The orientation of additional electrons inside the smaller magnet could be less than the induces re-orientation of electrons in the metal.
3. The force of attraction between a permanent magnet and a metal is stronger than between two permanent magnets.
   The crystalline metal structure is small in parts obtained by rapid cooling. The [magnetic domains](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/486687/46708) in such a metal developed poorly. This gives the probability of aligning many electrons in the metal, and this *could* end in a chain reaction of self-inductance; the metal transforms into a strong permanent magnet.
   Normally the metal is not a compound with rare earths, unlike the permanent magnets. Then the electron configuration of the metal does not lead to such a strong magnetic field as with permanent magnets.

Comment: So let's say I have two magnets of the same exact size and a piece of metal of the same size as well. The two magnets should have a stronger attraction versus the metal right? How much stronger would they be? 2X stronger?

Comment: I added a sentence to my answer.

Comment: How much stronger is it with two magnets compared to a magnet and metal in the example I gave?

Comment: My June 20th comment.

Comment: I can’t give you a quantitative answer. It depends very from the compounds. And I’m not sure that there is a realistic calculation at all. The experiment is the best way to get realistic results.

Comment: Ok that's fine. But I will say that the overall jargon is a bit confusing because the grammar isn't correct, but I'll throw you the check mark.

Comment: @Narcotixs You may edit my grammer.