# Effect of Exchange Interaction on Magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, exchange-interaction

My physics book says that the magnetic properties of ferromagnetic substances are a resultant of a process called **exchange coupling** in atoms, but unfortunately does not explain any why or how it does so.

I found these answers too, but unfortunately they doesn't answer my question completely: [Simple description of exchange interaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18395/284723) and [Ferromagnetism and induced magnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/486587/284723)

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. What is exchange coupling in a more intuitive sense (much of this I got from the aforementioned answer, but still need some clarity for what is going on *inside* the atom)?
2. How does exchange coupling affect magnetism, especially in the atoms of ferromagnetic substances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exchange interaction is a type of interaction between identical particles caused by permutation symmetry. In other words, it can be loosely thought of as a quantum statistical effect which results in a contribution to the Hamiltonian of a many-particle system (not directly from any fundamental forces). one of the most common exchange interaction is the Heisenberg interaction, where the Hamiltonian of 2 interacting spinful paricles reads:
$$
H_{12} = J\vec{S_1} \cdot \vec{S_2} = J(S_1^x \otimes S_2^x+S_1^y \otimes S_2^y+S_1^z \otimes S_2^z)
$$
where $J$ is a constant that set up the exchange energy scale, and $S_1,S_2$ are defined by Pauli matrices in their own Hilbert space.

A ferromagnetic chain (J<0) can be a result from the above exchange interaction. In the simplest case where the "chain" has only two spin-1/2 particles, $H_{12}$ reaches its minimum at triplet states, that is, fully magnetized in some direction. If $J>0$, its minimum energy occurs at singlet state where two spins anti-align to give zero magnetization. It's easy to check by diagonalizing $H_{12}$ and look at its eigen energy and corresponding eigen state. Longer macroscopic chain gives the same picture of magnetization.

Then you may wonder where does this $H_{12} \propto \vec{S_1} \cdot \vec{S_2}$ comes from at the first place. Well, there are many different physical systems that gives such exchange interaction. One canonical example is the Fermi Hubbard model, whereby Heisenberg type exchange interaction emerges due to the hopping of electrons between different sites and the on-site Coulumb repulsion between two anti-aligned electrons. This can be proved by 2nd order perturbation theory of the Hamiltonian:
$$
H = H_0 + H_1
$$
where $H_1$ describe the hopping between sites (kinetic energy) and $H_0$ the on-site electrostatic energy:
$$
H_0 \propto I \sum_{i,\sigma}n_{i,\sigma}n_{i,-\sigma}
,\;\;\;
H_1 \propto \sum_{ij,\sigma} T_{ij} c_{i,\sigma}^\dagger c_{i,\sigma}
$$
If $H_1$ is small compared to $H_0$, and notice the equivalence between spin operator and creation/annihilation operator:
$$
S_i^z = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\sigma} n_{i,\sigma},\;\;\; S_{i,\sigma} = c_{i,\sigma}^\dagger c_{i,-\sigma}
$$
the 2nd order perturbation theory will give you an effective Hamiltonian that has exchange interaction $H \propto \sum_{ij} S_i\cdot S_j + const$. For details you may refer to this pedagogical paper: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.10537

Comment: What happens in the case of paramagnetic and diamagnetic substances?

Comment: The answer can vary in different context. Phenomenologically, paramagnetic means the material tends to align to even weak magnetic field. In the context of condensed matter it is a phase where there's no spontaneous symmetry breaking (there's no preferred direction for spins, so its very susceptable). But there's no simple definitive Hamiltonian. Paramagnetic phase can occur in the ferromagnetic Hamiltonian at high temperature, at which the energy scale of exchange interaction is much smaller than energy induced by external field, hence spins would align to whichever direction of the field.